# Python Flask request.path loses its first path segment when deployed on Bluemix

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a Python Flask application that is deployed on Bluemix. When I run it locally, everything works as expected. However, when I make a request to the app on Bluemix, my request's path loses its first segment, which results in a `404`.

For instance, if I make a request to `/api/v1/items` and I execute a `print request.path` in my `app.before_request()` function, it prints `/v1/items` to the console.

App and environment details:

- Runtime: Python v2.7.10
- Flask Version: v0.10.1
- Platform: Bluemix
  Cloud Foundry

Of course I could simply issue every API request with a `/blah` prepended to the path, but that would be quite inelegant.

How is it that Flask is stripping the first segment of the path of my requests? Does anyone have any clues as to why this is happening and/or potential solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that I was calling the API from a REST client ([Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)) and using an environment variable for my hostname. I had a forward slash in both the env var and the request URL, causing the final sent request URL to have a double slash after the domain.

Thus, if you make an API request to a flask app with two forward slashes after the domain name (i.e. `myapi.com//api/v1/path`), the Python web server will remove the first path segment (`api/` in this case).